# Show text part of a multipart email in Gmail

Tags: gmail, text-formatting

An email sent with Content-Type of 'multipart/alternative' (often) contains two copies of the email: one HTML, one plaintext.

Gmail displays the HTML version of the email by default, but how do I view the plaintext contents, just to make sure that it looks right?

I can view the raw text using the "view original" option, but that's not really what I want; there's a lot of escapes visible when doing this, which is not what users would see.

Comment: I have the opposite problem, Gmail sometimes showing the text/plain  part , sometimes the text/html , but apparently randomly

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the "**Message text garbled?**" option in [Sarah's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/26734) was [removed from Gmail in mid-February 2017](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/_SqV5lak3Jg/GyLxkf8gDwAJ).

In the Gmail product forums, [user William25 posted this trickier but valid workaround](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/gmail/_SqV5lak3Jg/ZKcD03xEDgAJ).

> WORKAROUND!
>
> 1) From the "More" menu, select "Show original"
>
> 2) In the address bar, update the "view" parameter in the query string from "om" to "dom"
>
> You can also create this bookmark bar shortcut in Chrome and click on it instead of step 2 as listed above:
>   `javascript:window.location%3Dwindow.location.href.replace("view%3Dom%26th","view%3Ddom%26th")%3B`

Comment: If you're using the "new Gmail" design (as of June 2018), this no longer works. However, if you switch to "classic Gmail", it seems to work.

Comment: @rinogo Classic Gmail is no longer an option either, so we basically have no solution to this right now.

Comment: 2019: confirmed this doesn't work for 'Load basic html'

Comment: Does this mean, that plain text emails are a thing of past, and we shouldn't even bother sending a plain/text alternative even for those people who "prefer" plain text emails?

Comment: Great question @ShubhamKushwah - providing a plain text alternative alongside an HTML version is still necessary as spam filters like to see it i.e. it improves sender reputation (see https://www.litmus.com/blog/best-practices-for-plain-text-emails-a-look-at-why-theyre-important/)

Answer (score 0):

In 2019 you can go to the email menu `tree dots button (top right) -> Show original`

You should now see the text `Original message` on top.

Scroll down to `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`

The text should be below this.

This only works if the email has a text part.